# Activity creation events in workflow foundation 4

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I skimmed through the documentation but couldn't find an event handler to intercept activity creation in a workflow instance. I want to be notified whenever a new activity is created / entered.

Thanks.

Comment: Tracking service is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a tracking service will tell you when an activity started executing and when it is done. The [ActivityStateRecord](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.tracking.activitystaterecord_members(v=VS.100).aspx) is what you want to be looking at.

Comment: How can I run code "before" the activity executes? ActivityStateRecord works like a kind of logging mechanism, after the activity executes...

Comment: Without adding it to the workflow? I don't think you can replace the scheduler and inject some custom code just before every activity executes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that this is specifically supported, but I'm trying to find some options for you.

Can you provide a little more about your scenario and what type of work you want to do before each activity executes?

I'm asking if you can speak a little more about the dependencies that you are injecting. What is the business scenario that you are trying to accomplish?

Can you clarify why the following options are not sufficient?
* Rewrite the workflow to inject your custom activities prior to execution
* Embed the logic in your custom activities